# Xcode git Auto-Detect Email Error

Tags: xcode, git

With Xcode 7, I'm having a problem committing code to git.

```
I get this error:

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'stevex@stevebookpro.(none)')
```

I've tried the git commands suggested; when I run git config user.email in the repository I see a correct email address. I don't see where it's pulling the incorrect one from.

Comment: Even creating a new project exhibits this behaviour, and "git config --global user.email" shows a valid email address.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544188/xcode-7-gm-cant-commit-git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like most people, I expect, I had the correct *global* setting of user.email and user.name and never had problems with Xcode before.

I found that by making those settings **local** Xcode was happy again.

That is:

```
cd <YourCodeRepository>
xcrun git config user.email "you@example.com"
xcrun git config user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: Having an incorrect local config that's different from the global config is one possible problem, but unfortunately it's not the problem I'm having.  A brand new Xcode project, in a new repository, gives the same message.

Comment: That is really weird. I had a correct config, but the mail and name settings were not in the local config. The Xcode 7 release notes say 'The Xcode build system no longer automatically inherits the environment used to launch the app when running in the IDE.' So that gives a possible cause. I traced the system calls made by Xcode 7 and found it will open the .git directory for the current project (only). I suspect Xcode is simply checking the local project .git directory for the settings. But unfortunately that doesn't explain your issue.

Comment: I can confirm that a brand new Xcode project requires the email and name settings. Steps: 1. Create Project. 2. cd <Project Directory> 3. git init 4. Set (local) user.email and user.name. Xcode is ignoring the global settings (despite the message).

Comment: Well turns out you're right.  Even though, when I'd query the local setting it would give the correct value, explicitly setting it to the same value did fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one. There is even a special topci on apple [forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5000). I also tried by renaming global settings - nothing helped. Try using:

```
xcrun git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

but sadly for me it didn't work. I think they will fix this after official release. Until then, You must use Terminal, Source Tree or other tools.