# Xcode 7 GM can not authenticate git repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I could commit to this repository without problem with Xcode 6. git still works fine in terminal, i can commit both locally and to the remote. In Xcode 7, I can commit locally but not remotely. it says authentication fails and it is impossible to reset the username. (it's greyed out). I have the proper username in my local git config file. I've also tried to create a new account but I end up with the same problem of not being able to enter the userName.

my  git config --local --list

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@bitbucket.org:myUserName/myProject.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.failedTryToRename.remote=origin
branch.failedTryToRename.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master1.remote=origin
branch.master1.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=myUserName
user.email=myUserName@gmail.com
```

[image: XcodeAccountsScreen]

Comment: FWIW: I've got the same problem.

Comment: Me too.  Specifically with a bitbucket repo.  I don't see the Address and Type fields in the dialog though.

Comment: As a workaround, the SSH option (in the Authentication: field) worked for me.

Comment: command line for git worked for me, but I need from Xcode7

Comment: I used SSH Keys as Authentication, but it didn't work. (Error : The remote repository could not be found.) the setting was The quite same as Xcode 6.4, though.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the SSH remote URL:

```
remote.origin.url=git@bitbucket.org:myUserName/myProject.git
```

You will need to switch to the HTTPS remote URL.

```
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/myUserName/myProject.git
```

Alternatively, just give up. Stop trying to use Xcode's internal git management. (It's pretty terrible, so no harm done.) If you want a GUI, use SourceTree; it's from the same people who give you Bitbucket and works with it beautifully.

Comment: To use `ssh` he would need to create a private/public key, upload it to his bitbucket account then install it in his local `.ssh` profile.