# Xcode 7 not working properly with source control

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I just updated to Xcode 7, all system is updated, including command line tool, repaired disk permissions. And I still have several issues with that Xcode.

I am using GIT, but when I launch my project Xcode is ALWAYS asking me to upgrade to Subversion 1.7 even when I click on "Don't warn me again for this workspace" he does not remember.

[image]

When I quit and relaunch Xcode do not use my credential for GIT when I push he ALL the time ask me to type them.

When I go to preferences it builds up a stack of ghost buggy accounts...

[image]

And when I go to github, I realised that Xcode do not send my user.email when committing and pushing as I got a default email of ganzolo@noreply.github.com.

It's really annoying and buggy, does anybody have a clue?

I've removed SVN but still when I am doing a regular commit from command line (Git uses my user.email), when I am doing from Xcode he send like anonymous, really annoying.

[image]

Comment: You use git, but Libraries uses svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post I found a solution :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546171/706189

It appears that Xcode have a bug and do not read global user.name and user.email. Therefor you need to set it locally in your root folder project.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a subversion repo in your source tree, possibly in a 3rd-party library, that you are unaware of.

Go to Terminal and do this to upgrade it:

```
$ cd /path/to/sourcetree
$ find . -name .svn
```

If you get a hit then:

```
$ svn upgrade path/of/svnrepo
```

Better still dump the `.svn` directory and use git all the way through, if this 3rd-party library is also part of your permanent source tree.

Comment: Ok yes I know thanks for the commands, but the point is that Xcode should remember that I don't want to upgrade it.

Comment: @Ganzolo Yeah [it looks like](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/UpgradingtoSubversion1/UpgradingtoSubversion1.html) you could tell Xcode 5 to avoid reminders in the future.  Apple, eh?  Always doing something to make our lives more difficult.

Comment: This sort of worked for me. We no longer use SVN, but I couldn't find the .svn folders. The 'find' command showed me some hidden folders inside of the project file that contained other .svn directories. Right-clicking on these files and choosing Show Package Contents let me navigate to the hidden .svn folders.